# C++ Virtual Inheritance: static_cast "this" to virtual parent in initializer list of derived

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, lifetime, virtual-inheritance

I have some code. It doesn't work.

At first, you will look at this sample code snippet and think "WHY?" but trust me: there is a reason.

Here's the code:

```
class LinkedListNode
// blaa
{
public:
    LinkedListNode ( void* p )
    {
        // blaa
    }
} ;

template <typename T>
class InheritAndLinkList
:   public virtual T
,   public LinkedListNode
{
public:
    InheritAndLinkList ()
    :    LinkedListNode ( static_cast<void*>(static_cast<T*>(this)) ) // an exception occurs here when ..... (scroll down)
    { }
} ;

template <typename T>
class Implements
:   public virtual InheritAndLinkList<T>
{ } ;


class    A
{
public:
    virtual void goA () =0 ;
} ;

class    B
:   public Implements<A>
{
public:
    virtual void goB () =0 ;
} ;


class    MyClass
:   public Implements<B>
{
public:
    virtual void goA ()
    {
        // blaa
    }
    virtual void goB ()
    {
        // blaa
    }
} ;


int main ( ... )
{
    MyClass * p = new MyClass () ; // ..... This line executes

    p->goA() ;
    p->goB() ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

The specific error is that, upon construction, the expression `static_cast<T*>(this)` causes a segmentation fault....... when using the Intel C++ compiler. This has been working for years on many version of GCC, LLVM, MS Visual Studio, etc. And now ICPC makes it die.

I believe this is a perfectly valid thing to do. By the time this line gets called, `T` has been constructed and should be valid to use... unless there is another weird thing in the C++ spec about that.

Putting the `static_cast` in the constructor body (and changing its super to match) causes it to avoid this seg-fault.

So my question: **where in the spec does it say this *[static cast]* is/isn't safe?**

Comment: What exception are you getting? This compiles and runs fine on my system (g++)

Comment: Elaborating a bit more - the code you have here looks like it's totally fine (though the inheritance diagram took me a while to draw out ^_^), so I suspect something else is going on. Additionally, is this example sufficient to cause the crash (as in, should I expect this to crash when I run it?)

Comment: Not clear why you need all this virtual inheritance - you don't actually have a diamond-shaped hierarchy. There is a class that appears twice in the inheritance lattice - `LinkedListNode` - but that's precisely the one that you do *not* inherit virtually, and thus end up with two copies of in `MyClass`.

Comment: I know it's not clear why `virtual` is and isn't where it is, but there is a reason which shows up in larger systems (which consist of 90% of what I do). And I agree nothing is wrong with this code, but on the Intel C++ compiler, it has a segmentation fault.

Comment: @templatetypedef - "The specific error is that, upon construction, the expression `static_cast<T*>(this)` causes a segmentation fault....... when using the Intel C++ compiler."

Comment: Okay, so it's specifically a segmentation fault. I wasn't sure whether this was an idealized example or an actual minimal test case. Thanks!

Comment: @templatetypedef - I suppose one note: this is a derived example which exhibits nearly the exact same inheritance hierarchy as the case that's dying. That being said, I haven't yet tested *the exact code* in the example, but will in the next couple hours. I can't share the original code for proprietarity reasons.

Comment: @templatetypedef - OK, I have now tested the exact code above and it crashes with a segmentation fault in exactly the right spot (however, I do have to replace the ellipsis with the correct arguments or else ICPC will die anyway). Putting `static_cast<T*>(this)` in the constructor *body* works just fine, but putting it there in the initializer list doesn't work. So the question is still: is this spec behavior and GCC/MSVC/CLANG is nice? Or is this a bug in Intel's compiler? (if it's spec, what part of the spec?)

Comment: ICC has been relatively well known to have compiler bugs - I can specifically point out a third-party x64 version of Firefox that was compiled with ICC that resulted in a significant number of compiler bugs surfacing that Intel had to fix. Reliability also tends to vary significantly with compiler options chosen.

Comment: The `static_cast` is a distraction, this is just an up-cast, which can also be done implicitly (and is actually done as implicit conversion by `static_cast`. Removed non specific [tag:static-cast] tag, added the more specific [tag:up-casting]

Comment: The constructor starts the lifetime of the object, by first constructing the base classes, the members, and then establishing the object itself; the up cast works in the body of the constructor and not in the init-list; added [tag:constructor] and [tag:lifetime] for that reason.

Comment: @curiousguy That can't possibly be true, or at least not universally true all of the time. There's an example in **[class.cdtor]/3** that shows up-casting of `this` in constructor initializer list and declares it to be valid. Also, it's OK to use some members to initialize other members (if you are careful about the order), and member access uses `this` implicitly. Could you cite chapter and verse suggesting that `this` is not valid in initializer list? It doesn't make any sense - how else would the program even locate members to be initialized?

Comment: @curiousguy "**[class.base.init]/15** [*Note*: Because the *mem-initializer* are evaluated in the scope of the constructor, the `this` pointer can be used in the *expression-list* of a *mem-initializer* to refer to the object being initialized. — *end note*]" And like I said, there's an example in **[class.cdtor]/3** that upcasts `this` and passes the result of that upcast to base class constructor, in the initializer list; it initializes one base class with the pointer to the other.

Comment: @curiousguy "**[class.cdtor]/3** To explicitly or implicitly convert a pointer (a glvalue) referring to an object of class `X` to a pointer (reference) to a direct or indirect base class `B` of `X`, the construction of `X` and the construction of all of its direct or indirect bases that directly or indirectly derive from `B` shall have started ..., otherwise the conversion results in undefined behavior." You seem to argue that the constructor "starts" only when opening brace of its body is reached - but again, an example right under that clause clearly contradicts such interpretation.

Comment: @curiousguy Yes, some uses can - **[class.base.init]/16** explicitly spells them out. But upcast of `this` is not one of them, and in fact is explicitly allowed under certain carefully prescribed conditions - which I believe the OP's code satisfies.

Comment: @curiousguy "**[class.base.init]/16** Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be called for an object under construction.
Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or of a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7). However, if these operations are performed in a *ctor-initializer* (or in a function called directly or indirectly from a *ctor-initializer*) before all the *mem-initializer*s for base classes have completed, the result of the operation is undefined." But the OP's code does none of the three prohibited actions.

Comment: FWIW, the exact same text was already in N1905. It's very old spec, not a moving standard target.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Your last comment is the answer to this question; I highly recommend you add this to your answer. Up-casting to a virtual base class **is** is [special] dynamic cast because the location of the superclass depends on the dynamic type of the object, not its static type - and therefore must ask the dynamic type where it is.

Comment: @iAdjunct Up-casting is specifically addressed by **[class.cdtor]/3**, which I did too add to my answer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that example isn't quite the same thing though since the class which needs the vtable to know where its super is already has finished construction, whereas in my example it hasn't.

Comment: @iAdjunct The example has `X(this)`, where `this` is `E*`. `E` has not finished construction, considering that `X(this)` is in `E`'s constrructor's initializer list. In your example, `LinkedListNode ( static_cast<void*>(static_cast<T*>(this)) )` is in a similar position, with `LinkedListNode` for `X` and `InheritAndLinkList<T>` for `E`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But in that example, E to any of its parents is a static cast (offset known at compile-time). At that point, you're in a constructed class (in the example), and the conversion to its parent is a dynamic cast (due to the virtual inheritance). In my case, I'm casting from this to a virtual parent in that first step.

Comment: @iAdjunct That very same example also says that `D(this)` is UB. Why would that be if the cast from `E*` to `A*` were purely static? In any case, the text of the standard doesn't make this distinction between "dynamic" and "static" you are trying to make. It describes under what conditions a pointer-to-derived can be converted to a pointer-to-base. If you want to argue that this paragraph is inapplicable, you have to explain precisely which conditions are being violated and how (especially since you yourself demanded a language-lawyerly answer).

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, the code looks OK to me. I don't see anything controversial in this use of `static_cast` - it's run-of-the-mill derived-to-base pointer conversion. Looks like a compiler bug to me.

If you insist on chapter and verse:

> **[expr.static.cast]/4** An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

So we are looking at the validity of `T t(this);` within the constructor of `InheritAndLinkList<T>` - a *direct-initialization*:

> **[dcl.init]/17** ...
>
> -- Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression. Standard conversions (Clause 4) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered.

.

> **[conv.ptr]/3** A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `D`”, where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>   to *cv* `B`”, where `B` is a base class (Clause 10) of `D`. If `B` is an inaccessible (Clause 11) or ambiguous (10.2) base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a
>   pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object.

---

**EDIT**

After vigorous discussion in comments, using `this` from within constructor initializer list is not quite as straightforward - but your particular use is still legal, I believe.

> **[class.cdtor]/3** To explicitly or implicitly convert a pointer (a glvalue) referring to an object of class `X` to a pointer (reference) to a direct or indirect base class `B` of `X`, the construction of `X` and the construction of all of its direct or indirect bases that directly or indirectly derive from `B` shall have started and the destruction of these classes shall not have completed, otherwise the conversion results in undefined behavior... [*Example*:
>
> ```
> struct A { };
> struct B : virtual A { };
> struct C : B { };
> struct D : virtual A { D(A*); };
> struct X { X(A*); };
>
> struct E : C, D, X {
>   E() : D(this), // undefined: upcast from E* to A*
>                  // might use path E* ! D* ! A*
>                  // but D is not constructed
>                  // D((C*)this), // defined:
>                  // E* ! C* defined because E() has started
>                  // and C* ! A* defined because
>                  // C fully constructed
>   X(this) {      // defined: upon construction of X,
>                  // C/B/D/A sublattice is fully constructed
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Your case resembles `X(this)` in the example above, and is actually simpler than that because you only cast one step up in the hierarchy, so there are no intermediate classes to be concerned about.

Comment: I agree it looks like that and I'm pretty sure it is that. The question really stems from it being a virtual base class that it's casting to.

Comment: The dawn of an object: before `typeid` and virtual functions can be used, after virtual base classes are made accessible! GCC uses one hidden field for all of these, the vptr; may be the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

*It may be a compiler bug*.

I reduced and simplified the code example:

```
struct ctor_takes_int
{
    // dummy parameter needed to put expression in a ctor-init-list of derived class
    ctor_takes_int (int=0){ }
} ;

struct stupid_base
{
    //int nevermind;
} ;

struct upcast_in_init_list;

/* 
 * volatile = anti optimisation :
 * no value propagation possible on volatile variables
 * no constant propagation
 * no inlining of volatile pointer to function!
 */
int (*volatile upcast) (struct upcast_in_init_list *that);

struct upcast_in_init_list
: virtual stupid_base, ctor_takes_int
{
    upcast_in_init_list ()
    :    ctor_takes_int (upcast(this))
    { }
} ;

/*
 * volatile = anti optimisation
 * no dead assignment removal
 */
stupid_base *volatile p;

// must be compiled out of line
int do_upcast (upcast_in_init_list *that) {
    p = that;
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    upcast = &do_upcast;
    new upcast_in_init_list() ; 
    return 0 ;
}
```

The program crashes on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

(Note the use of `volatile` to prevent some optimisations, but it doesn't seem needed in practice. It's just more "robust", to have a "robust crash".)

If instead of calling a function, I do the up cast inside the ctor-init-list, with `((p = this,0))`, the program works. This means that the compilers knows how to perform the pointer conversion on `this` inside the ctor-init-list of the object being constructor, but the common conversion code doesn't know how perform the conversion, as the derived object doesn't exist at that point (you can't use `typeid` on it for example).

When you think about it in term of implementation, it's understandable: for non virtual base classes, the derived to base pointer conversion is a simple "if non null add a fixed offset" adjustment, but it involves something more complicated for virtual base classes, as they don't reside at a fixed offset, by definition (making a base class virtual is much like adding a level of indirection).

The essence of virtual items (virtual functions, virtual base classes) is a dependency on the dynamic (real) type of the object. Note that a class without virtual functions but with a virtual base class isn't "polymorphic" in C++ and doesn't support RTTI (`dynamic_cast` and `typeid`), but must still have some "virtual" runtime information, either vptr (vtable pointer), or some virtual base offset or pointer. In either case, the runtime information is initialized during construction.

**When the body of a constructor is entered (immediately after `{`), the object being constructed doesn't officially "exists"** as its lifetime has not started: if the constructor body exits with an exception, the corresponding destructor will not be invoked. But the un-started lifetime still has all the attribute of a "virtual" object (= an object with virtual features, either functions or base classes). Virtual functions can be called virtually and the overrider in the current class will be invoked, `typeid` will indicate the type of the object in construction, etc.

In practice, conversions to non virtual base classes always work, in all compilers, as no "virtual"/dynamic information is used, just like calling non virtual functions "works" (in practice) on un-constructed objects, even if it isn't legal.

Also, conversion of the expression (not value) `this` in the initialization list works, as it is a special optimized case: the compiler knows the layout of the class and the (static) offset of all virtual in the complete constructor (the constructor used to construct complete objects, not base class subobjects). You can see that `this` is special cased: using `(that = this, p = that, 0)` (where `that` is some `upcast_in_init_list *` variable) in a ctor-init-list of a complete constructor doesn't work, as the special isn't recognized anymore.

Handling of `this` is a base class constructor call (a constructor call that doesn't get to initialize virtual base classes) apparently works too, I don't know why.

Comment: Quite frankly, looks like a compiler bug to me. It works with clang and msvc, only crashes with gcc (which I don't have handy to debug). **[class.cdtor]/3** explicitly addresses this precise situation, and has an example that closely resembles yours and declares it valid.

Comment: As clear as can be: "**[class.base.init]/15** [*Note*: Because the *mem-initializer* are evaluated in the scope of the constructor, the `this` pointer can be used in the *expression-list* of a *mem-initializer* to refer to the object being initialized. — *end note*]" Now, it's a non-normative note, but it's clearly the intent of the standard to allow such usage.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If it's a bug, at least I have a nicer and simpler code snippet than the very complicated hierarchy in the question. ;)

Comment: I changed the answer to indicate: It may be a compiler bug.

Comment: You're missing a key point: it's a virtual base class. This is ridiculously important.